# Как в EditText сделать начало ввода не с середины

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditText если больше 1 символа в ширину начинает ввод с центра, но так не красиво. Как сделать чтобы ввод начинался не с середины EditText а с верха.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используй параметр gravity в разметке. Там есть очень много вариантов, попробуй думаю поможет.
gravity = "top|left"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Точно спс, помогло. Мог бы и сам догадаться.